# How to synchronize communication on UDP protocol?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp

I ran a simulation test to understand the problem that I am facing with UDP communication.

### Setup

I have a host on which 4 UDP Clients are running, each in its own thread (T1, T2, T3, and T4). T1 and T2 share one DatagramSocket object called *socket*, while T3 and T4 share one DatagramSocket object called *socket2*.

T1 and T2 are sending and receiving an echo from a UDP Server at IP (say) *udpServer1* while T3 and T4 are communicating with *udpServer2*.

### Problem

I was able to synchronize T1 and T2 which share the same DatagramSocket and Runnable objects when running the threads in parallel. However, when tried running T1 and T3 which are using different DatagramSocket and Runnable objects, T3 always failed with SocketTimeoutException, but T1 could send and receive packets with no problem.

In summary:

1. Running T1 and T2 (or T3 and T4) in parallel, sharing same DatagramSocket and Runnable objects --> OK
2. Running T1 and T3 in parallel, each using its own DatagramSocket and Runnable objects --> SocketTimeoutException on one of them.

### Questions

Why does T3 keeps on getting SocketTimeoutException even when it's on its own DatagramSocket and running on its own thread? What did I do wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

### Test codes

```
@Test
public void sendRemoteTest() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(9987, InetAddress.getByName(localMachineIp));
    DatagramSocket socket2 = new DatagramSocket(9988, InetAddress.getByName(localMachineIp));
    UdpClientRunnable runnable = new UdpClientRunnable(socket, 1);
    UdpClientRunnable runnable2 = new UdpClientRunnable(socket2, 1);
   
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
    t1.setName("T1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
    t2.setName("T2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(runnable2);
    t3.setName("T3");
    Thread t4 = new Thread(runnable2);
    t4.setName("T4");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}

private byte toByte(int num) {
    return (byte) ((byte) (0xFF) & num);
}

public class UdpClientRunnable implements Runnable {
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private long delayMillis;
    private byte[] dataToSend;

    public UdpClientRunnable(DatagramSocket socket, long delayMilis) {
       this.socket = socket;
       this.delayMillis = delayMilis;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
       byte[] data1 = new byte[] { toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01),
          toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01) };
       byte[] data2 = new byte[] { toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02),
          toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02) };
       byte[] data3 = new byte[] { toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03),
          toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03) };
       byte[] data4 = new byte[] { toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04),
          toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04) };

       String targetIp = "";
       String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
       if (name.contains("T1")) {
          dataToSend = data1;
          targetIp = udpServer1;
       }
       else if (name.contains("T2")){
          dataToSend = data2;
          targetIp = udpServer1;
       }
       else if (name.contains("T3")) {
          dataToSend = data3;
          targetIp = udpServer2;
       }
       else {
          dataToSend = data4;
          targetIp = udpServer2;
       }
       int count = 0;
       while (count < 250) {
          try {
             sendAndReceive(targetIp, name, count, dataToSend);
             Thread.sleep(delayMillis);
          }
          catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(e + ": " + name + ", iter: " + count);
          }
          finally {
             ++count;
          }
       }
    }

    private synchronized void sendAndReceive(String targetIp, String threadName, int count, byte[] dataToSend) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, SocketException {
        byte[] rcvData = new byte[5];
        DatagramPacket rcvPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvData, rcvData.length);
        socket.send(new DatagramPacket(dataToSend, 5, InetAddress.getByName(targetIp), 9999));
        socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
        rcvPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvData, rcvData.length);
        socket.receive(rcvPacket);
        printData(threadName, count, rcvData);
        if (threadName.contains("T1")) {
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(new byte[] { toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01),
                toByte(0x01), toByte(0x01) }, rcvData);
        }
        else if (threadName.contains("T2")){
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(new byte[] { toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02),
                toByte(0x02), toByte(0x02) }, rcvData);
        }
        else if (threadName.contains("T3")){
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(new byte[] { toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03),
                toByte(0x03), toByte(0x03) }, rcvData);
        }
        else if (threadName.contains("T4")){
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(new byte[] { toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04),
                toByte(0x04), toByte(0x04) }, rcvData);
        }
    }

    private void printData(String name, int count, byte[] rcvData) {
        String prefix = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < rcvData.length; i++) {
            prefix = (i == 0) ? (name + " iter " + count + ": ") : "";
            System.out.print(prefix + Integer.toHexString((byte) ((byte) (0xFF) & rcvData[i])) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  
}
```

Comment: For one thing, UDP datagrams can be lost. So not receiving everything that's sent should be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code so there is two server located in two different machine I presume listening to the same port 999. As such I think the problem might lie with the server code. Are you doing this when you respond back to the client

```
byte[] rcvData = new byte[5];
DatagramPacket rcvPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvData, rcvData.length);
socket.receive(rcvPacket);
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(rcvPacket.getData(), rcvPacket.getLength(), rcvPacket.getAddress(), rcvPacket.getPort());  // note that here we need to use the received packet information on where to send the response back
socket.send(sendPacket);
```

Few additional comments

1. Make the constructor UdpClientRunnable to take to additional input destination port and  destination address so that you do not need to have all the if else block inside
2. Remove synchronized keyword from `sendAndReceive` as `run` is already synchronized

Comment: Thanks, @tabiul. It turned out that there was a problem with the UDP server. Really appreciate your time looking into this.